# How to export a table object to Excel

Tags: r, export, export-to-excel

I would like to export a table object to Excel from R.

I generate a reproducible table as below:

```
a <- as.numeric(round(runif(20,-40,40),2))

b <- as.numeric(round(a*1.4+60,2))

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a, b))

t <-table(df$a,df$b)
```

Is it possible to export the table object to Excel, and keep the table format?

Answer (score 0):

You could use XLConnect. It will export to your workingdirectory.

```
library(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook("name.xlsx"), create = TRUE)
createSheet(wb, name="sheetname")
writeWorksheet(wb,t,"sheetname",startRow = 3, startCol 
+ = 1, header = FALSE)
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

Comment: This one gives what I want when apply to the example table, although it transpose the table. But I don't know why it does not work in another table object in my data. Would it because of the transpose?

Comment: I have edit my question. I generated a table from a data frame using the table() function. But XLConnect does not give the desired layout

Answer (score 0):

Just transpose it

```
data <- table(rpois(100, 6))
write.table(t(data),"clipboard",sep="\t",row.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE)
```

And the paste:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  13
1   5   8   10  22  18  16  9   5   4   2
```

Translation to `write.csv` or `write.xlsx` should be clear.

Comment: is it possible to export to excel automatically?

Comment: Use whatever method you are currently using, e.g. `write.xlsx`. The question was how to get output in the desired layout. This answer is to simply transpose it. Use of clipboard here is just for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think another way would be convert the table into a dataframe, with as.data.frame.matrix(table) function.